# From mathematical partition function to "thermodynamics"

Tags: mathematical-physics, entropy

The entropy of a probability distribution $\rho$ is:

$$
S[\mathbb{Q},\rho]=-k_B \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \rho[\mathbb{Q},q] \ln \rho[\mathbb{Q},q] \tag{1}
$$

Let the following be constraints:

$$
\overline{E}_1 = \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} E_1[q] \rho[q]\\
\vdots\\
\overline{E}_n = \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} E_n[q] \rho[q]\\
1=\sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}\rho[q]
$$

The probability measure that maximizes the entropy under these constraints is the Gibbs measure:

$$
\rho[\mathbb{Q},q,\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n] = \frac{1}{Z[\mathbb{Q},\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n]}\exp(-\beta_1 E_1[q] - \dots - \beta_n E_n[q]) \tag{2}
$$

$$
\text{where }Z[\mathbb{Q},\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n]=\sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \exp (-\beta_1 E_1[q] - \dots - \beta_n E_n[q]) 
$$

Replacing (2) into (1), we eventually get:

$$
S[\mathbb{Q},\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n]=k_B \ln Z[\mathbb{Q},\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n]+\beta_1\overline{E}_1[\mathbb{Q},\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n]+\dots+\beta_n\overline{E}_n[\mathbb{Q},\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n]
$$

and its total derivative is:

$$
dS[\mathbb{Q},\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n]=\beta_1d\overline{E}_1[\mathbb{Q},\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n]+\dots+\beta_nd\overline{E}_n[\mathbb{Q},\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n]\tag{3}
$$

---

I am trying to understand thermodynamics from a strong mathematical footing, but I wasn't able to find any physics textbook that addresses the following issue:

Thermodynamics starts from the fundamental relation (3), appears to ignore the dependence of $\overline{E}_i$ on its variables $[\mathbb{Q}, \beta_1,\dots,\beta_n]$, instead postulates that they are independent variables and then draws conclusions dependant upon this erasure. With the switcharoo, the relation becomes:

$$
dS[\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n,\overline{E}_1,\dots,\overline{E}_n]=\beta_1d\overline{E}_1+\dots+\beta_nd\overline{E}_n
$$

As an example, consider the simple case where dS depends only on one thermodynamic pair:

$$
dS[\beta,\overline{E}]=\beta d\overline{E}
$$

In thermodynamics, one often claims that the temperature quantities the 'number of times' one must doubling the energy, while maintaining the temperature constant, to doubles the entropy. Other claims, also dependant upon the erasure, are made regarding the ability to draw cycles over the independent variables, etc.

However, inspecting the true dependance of $S$ and $\overline{E}$ one finds that the energy cannot be doubled without changing $\beta$. Explicitly, one must change $\beta$ to change anything at all:

$$
dS[\beta]=\beta d\overline{E}[\beta]
$$

Since thermodynamics depends upon these claims, my question is then how do we save thermodynamics using the formalism above as the starting point?

---

I have explicitly included the dependance on $\mathbb{Q}$ (which is not normally done) as a last-ditch effort to save thermodynamics. The full dependence is actually:

$$
dS[\mathbb{Q},\beta]=\beta d\overline{E}[\mathbb{Q},\beta]
$$

Is thermodynamics then saved by 'changing $\mathbb{Q}$ while maintaining $\beta$ constant (so as to double the energy while keeping $\beta$ constant)'? Its the only thing left to work.

Comment: "In thermodynamics, one often claims that doubling the energy, while maintaining the temperature constant, doubles the entropy." I have not heard this claim and it should be false in general. The claim I have heard is that if you double the _system_, that energy and entropy both double (while temperature remains the same). That is, energy and entropy are extrinsic quantities (while temperature is an intrinsic quantity).

Comment: @s.harp What explicitely is the "system" in my equations? Is it $\mathbb{Q}$. What does double it means --- doubling the size of the set $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: You have a probability distribution $P$ on a space of states $X$ (I think for you $\Bbb Q= X$). Doubling the system corresponds to to looking at the probability distribution on $X\times X$ given by $P_{new}(A\times B) = P_{old}(A)\cdot P_{old}(B)$. You can quickly show that the entropy doubles by doing this, the new energy function on this system is $E_{new}(x_1,x_2) = E_{old}(x_1)+E_{old}(x_2)$ and the total energy will also double.$$\, $$
Think about doubling as if your system were a box, and you now take a second identical but seperate box and consider both of them together as the system.

Comment: @s.harp So then, if my goal is say, to double the energy without changing the temperature, I can achieve this goal by suitably increasing the size of the system in the manner which you have described? The temperature, as it is intensive, will remain constant, correct?

Comment: Yes, take two non-interacting copies of the same system. The extrinsic quantities (like entropy, energy, volume etc) will double, while the intrinsic quantities (temperature, pressure etc) will remain the same. ("Non-interacting" is a bit of a red herring, thermodynamics doesn't really care about dynamics, what I mean more concretely by it is that the probability distribution behaves like before and the energy function of a pair of states $(x_1, x_2)$ is the sum $E(x_1)+E(x_2)$.)

Comment: @s.harp Thanks, if you feel like committing your comment as an answer, I will accept it.